# How to position buttons when using Vuetify hover component with z index

Tags: hover, vuetify.js, css-position, z-index

Imagine I have e.g. following component:

```
<template>
  <div class="alignment-div-outer">
    <div class="first-button">
      <v-btn>
        First Button
      </v-btn>
    </div>
    <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
      <div class="alignment-div-outer">
        <div v-if="hover" class="alignment-div-inner">
          <v-btn class="hover-button">
            Hover Button 1
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn class="hover-button">
            Hover Button 2
          </v-btn>
        </div>
        <div>
          <v-btn>
            Second Button
          </v-btn>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-hover>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.alignment-div-outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.alignment-div-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-button {
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover-button {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Unfortunately I don't know what I have to do to position the 'Hover button' next to the 'Second button' on the left side. I've searched alot about z-index and the Vuetify hover component but I didn't found a real useful example.

Can anyone give me a hint how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to archive, but if you remove the `.hover-button` class, the three buttons are next to each other. Feel free to make your question more specific, maybe add an image of what you want to achieve.